# unexpected identifier while spinning the server

Tags: node.js, async-await

I am making a simple node js app using MVC. 
Here is my model:

```
const db = require('../util/database');

class Channel {
  constructor(channel_id,channel_name, price, language, isActive, genre) {
    this.channel_id = channel_id;
    this.channel_name = channel_name;
    this.language = language;
    this.isActive = isActive;
    this.genre = genre;
    this.price = price;
  }

  static fetchAll() {
    return db.execute('SELECT * FROM channel');
  }
```

Here is my controller:

```
const Channel = require('../models/channel');

class AdminController {
  constructor(){

  }
  async static getChannels(req,res){
    let channels = await Channel.fetchAll();
    res.send(channels);
  }
}

module.exports = AdminController;
```

Here are my routes:

```
const express = require('express');
const adminController = require('../controllers/admin');
const router = express.Router();
router.get('/all-channels', adminController.getChannels);
module.exports = router;
```

But the problem is when I am trying to spin the server, it says `unexpected identifier async static getChannels(req,res){` 
Where am I doing wrong?
P.S. I am new to NodeJs

Answer (score 0):

first thing you have require your route file inside index.js 
like **app.use('/', yourRouteFile);**
and second one you have change in route file **router.route('/data').get(adminController.getChannels);**
and static async syntax
I think so now it's helpful for you.

Comment: yes, my bad, it would be static async. Already corrected it. But I want to encapsulate the prefix. That's why encountered with such a tiny issue. thanks, buddy.